# What is the current "state of the art" for unicode math?

Tags: unicode-math

Unicode Technical Report #25 provides comprehensive information about the character repertoire, their properties, and guidelines for implementation and I understand Barbara Beeton from the AMS, was part of the committee that drafted it. There some 3000 codepoints allocated in the various math blocks. We also have unicode-math, which bridges some of the gaps, although still is lacking to integrate fully all the LuaTeX properties. It will be a blessing to the pdf tagging project if unicode-math gets wider adoption, as already happened with the adoption of unicode for general text. I am also intrigued by the possibility, that it might be possible to develop a shaper engine to render mathematics at least partially outside TeX, at least for some parts.

My question is to find out, where we stand at present. Is there more work being done at the AMS level with unicode? Are there roadmaps for unicode-math and the tagging project? Are societies like the AMS working at adoption at least at future date?

Comment: there's some work going on (slowly) for an update to tr25, mainly just fixing reported errors. As for work outside tex see https://w3c.github.io/mathml-core/ which specifies the math layout based on the opentype math spec that is used in current desktop web browsers

Comment: ACM? No, it’s AMS, a very different organization.

Comment: @egreg Sorry my bad, I will edit

Comment: also of course the de facto reference implementation of the Unicode Opentype Math layout is Microsoft Word/ Cambria Math as the specification derives from the Implementation report of office Math.

Comment: Since retiring from the AMS in 2019, I've had only "spectator" connection with Unicode activities.  I don' know for sure, but suspect strongly that the AMS has merely filed away the resources I left behind, and no one is paying attention to this.  @DavidCarlisle has pretty much taken my place with regard to UTR #25, so believe what he says.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks a lot.